# Why does g++ 11 trigger "maybe uninitialized" warning in connection with this pointer casting

Tags: c++, g++

After a compiler update from g++ v7.5 (Ubuntu 18.04) to v11.2 (Ubuntu 22.04), the following code triggers the `maybe-uninitialized` warning:

```
#include <cstdint>

void f(std::uint16_t v)
{
  (void) v;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int pixel = 0;
    std::uint16_t *f16p = reinterpret_cast<std::uint16_t*>(&pixel);
    f(*f16p);
}
```

Compiling on Ubuntu 22.04, g++ v11.2 with `-O3 -Wall -Werror`.

The example code is a reduced form of a real use case, and its ugliness is not the issue here.

Since we have `-Werror` enabled, it leads to a build error, so I'm trying figure out how to deal with it right now. Is this an instance of [this gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102329), or is there an other explanation for the warning?

https://godbolt.org/z/baaMTxhae

Comment: *"its ugliness is not the issue here."* I suspect the ugliness actually is the issue. The compiler might not be able to successfully statically analyze the code through the `reinterpret_cast` and the Undefined Behavior that results from it. In this case it isn't really a false positive, more likely an incorrect diagnosis, because the code actually is broken. Not for the reason the compiler states, but that stated reason is probably the cause of the misdiagnosis, so not entirely incorrect either.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior.  You are violating the strict aliasing rule

Comment: *"Is this an instance of this gcc bug"* Note that since your code has Undefined Behavior on all paths, it cannot stand as evidence of a compiler bug.

Comment: Using `reinterpret_cast` you are telling the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing, don't nag me and just do what I'm telling you to do".  Alas, in this situation that is not the case.  I recommend not using `reinterpret_cast` here.

Comment: That cast looks scary and I for one suspect it might be [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @NathanOliver: For cases where `int` is 16 bits and `std::uint16_t` aliases `unsigned int`, it is not UB ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Does ubuntu 20.04 run on a system with a 16 bit in? ;)

Comment: Why not just make `pixel` a `uint16_t` and ditch the cast?

Comment: @JesperJuhl In the end I had to rewrite the original code to remove the cast. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize an object of type `std::uint16_t`, so it is used uninitialized.

This error is suppressed by `-fno-strict-aliasing`, allowing `pixel` to be accessed through a `uint16_t` lvalue.
Note that `-fstrict-aliasing` is the default at `-O2` or higher.
It could also be fixed with a [`may_alias`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-may_005falias-type-attribute) pointer:

```cpp
using aliasing_uint16_t = std::uint16_t [[gnu::may_alias]];
aliasing_uint16_t* f16p = reinterpret_cast<std::uint16_t*>(&pixel);
f(*f16p);
```

Or you can use [`std::start_lifetime_as`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2590r2.pdf):

```cpp
static_assert(sizeof(int) >= sizeof(std::uint16_t) && alignof(int) >= alignof(std::uint16_t));

// (C++23, not implemented in g++11 or 12 yet)
auto *f16p = std::start_lifetime_as<std::uint16_t>(&pixel);

// (C++17)
auto *f16p = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<std::uint16_t*>(new (&pixel) char[sizeof(std::uint16_t)]));
```